# How to find out tablix width to set chart's DynamicWidth equal to matrix's width?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The requirements call for placing a chart above the matrix and them having the same width.
Depending on how many years the user wants to report/chart, the number of columns and width of the matrix will change. How can I query the width of the matrix tablix to set chart's DynamicWidth to that value?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the chart in the tablix and format the tablix with the correct spacing, etc., to have the layout you want. I'll always have the same response - everything should be in a tablix.  This then locks the chart size to the tablix size.

EDIT: That being said, I'm pretty sure functionality to get something like: Tablix.size.width property at runtime doesn't exist.

When you consume the report programmatically the datasets in XML don't make sense if everything is in a floating text box. For instance, when you call the report from C# and try to parse datasets, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Which function gets tablix size? And I am not aware of any way to insert a chart into a matrix. How can that be achieved?

Comment: I just took one of my matrices, right-clicked the top row, did Insert Row - Outside Group Above,  and copied my chart in. As for the function to get the tablix size at runtime - I have no idea. IF there was a way to get those values (I don't think there are) you could write a function using them, but I don't think that's an option.

Comment: Is your chart now between the header row and data?

Comment: It should be on top of the header row.  I "Insert Row - Outside Group Above" so it wouldn't be repeated for each row in the tablix.  You can add multiple rows above your header row, so you can add one or more blank, non-repeating, rows to buffer or otherwise control the distance between the chart and the headers.

Comment: I understand your approach, but it has side effects: the chart becomes too narrow when there are too few columns in the matrix, or the matrix columns become too wide.

Comment: And it actually scales the small copy of the chart, so it becomes summarily useless. I don't know how to get the chart to properly size in this scenario.

Comment: Ah, bummer. It becomes too big and too small?  Can the shrinkage be fixed by setting CanShrink = False? It sounds like you have a real challenge here.